# Stripping two characters from a string PHP using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of html tags of the form

```
<a>
<div>
...
```

How would I strip the `<>` away from the strings to return the word in between using regular expressions?

Attempts:

```
preg_replace('~<>~', ' ', $tag);, preg_replace("[<>]", ' ', $tag);, and preg_replace(array(">","<"), " ", $tag);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? As you have explained the problem, this is extremely straightforward, even without regular expressions.

Comment: I have. I am brand new to regex and have found the documentation rather overwhelming. I've tried thus far `preg_replace('~<>~', ' ', $tag);`, `preg_replace("[<>]", '  ', $tag);`, and `preg_replace(array(">","<"), " ", $tag);`, to no avail. I've been trying things out for 30 minutes to no avail. I don't understand why I'm being downvoted. Is this not the place to ask questions?

Comment: @socrates if you had included some of those in your question, you might not have gotten as many downvotes, if any. As it stands, you literally asked people to code it for you, which is definitely not what questions on StackOverflow should be about. It's fine to ask for help if you've tried something and it didn't work. The downvote caption reads "does not show any research effort" and indeed your question _showed_ none. Keep in mind that people cannot know what you haven't told them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

Based on your examples, the problem is that you are not using delimiters. You must use a delimiter (typically `/`, but often `~`). From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (`/`), hash signs (`#`) and tildes (`~`). The following are all examples of valid delimited patterns.
>
> `/foo bar/`
> `#^[^0-9]$#`
> `+php+`
> `%[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%`

## The Solution

So, your code could be:

```
$newString = preg_replace("/[<>]/", ' ', $tag);
```

Here's a [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vU9iG5/1), showing how it works.

Comment: thank you. for future reference i guess i'll include attempts at solving a problem as as proof-of-work.

Comment: @socrates Yes, you generally need to include a [mcve], which means you need to say, "Here's what I want to do, what I've tried, and the specific problem or error I got."